# How to solve a set of equations where the unknowns are a function and some parameters?

Tags: matrices, functions, functional-equations

I’d like to know how to solve something like this:
\begin{align}
f(f(x_2)-f(x_1)) & = 27.5\\
f(f(x_3)-f(x_1)) & = 21.6\\
f(f(x_4)-f(x_1)) & = 15.1\\
f(f(x_5)-f(x_1)) & = 10.2\\
f(f(x_6)-f(x_1)) & = \ \ 8.8\\
f(f(x_7)-f(x_1)) & = \ \ 8.4\\
f(f(x_8)-f(x_1)) & = \ \ 7.8\\
f(f(x_9)-f(x_1)) & = \ \ 6.4\\
f(f(x_4)-f(x_3)) & = 46.5\\
f(f(x_5)-f(x_3)) & = 17.6\\
f(f(x_5)-f(x_4)) & = 28\\
f(f(x_7)-f(x_4)) & = 20.1\\
f(f(x_9)-f(x_7)) & = 22
\end{align}
where I’m looking for $f(x)$ and $x_1$, $x_2$, $\ldots$, $x_9$.  It is given that $0<x_1<x_2<\ldots< x_9$ and that $f(x)$ is a decreasing function which we have reasons to believe is linear.  (Also, there’s a margin of error of about $\pm 0.2$.)

Comment: Could you write the complete set of equations?  Are you sure the first three equations are correct?  The remaining equations are hard to predict given the first three equations.

Comment: Heres what I've got so far (there's a margin of error of about +-0.2):  
f(f(x2) - f(x1)) = 27.5  ; 
f(f(x3) - f(x1)) = 21.6  ; 
f(f(x4) - f(x1)) = 15.1  ; 
f(f(x5) - f(x1)) = 10.2  ; 
f(f(x6) - f(x1)) = 8.8  ; 
f(f(x7) - f(x1)) = 8.4  ; 
f(f(x8) - f(x1)) = 7.8  ; 
f(f(x9) - f(x1)) = 6.4  ; 
f(f(x4) - f(x3)) = 46.5  ; 
f(f(x5) - f(x3)) = 17.6  ; 
f(f(x5) - f(x4)) = 28  ; 
f(f(x7) - f(x4)) = 20.1 ; 
f(f(x9) - f(x7)) = 22

Comment: Let me edit your question for you.  In the future, use MathJax (see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/18398).

Comment: Do we have any information about $f(x)$?  For example, is it linear, exponential, etc.?  Right now I can't see a way of solving it without additional information.

Comment: We know that it is a decreasing function, and we have reason to believe it's linear, also all the unknowns are positive.

Comment: I've edited your question again.  In the future, I suggest you write in the post all the information you have about the problem, to help people help you.  I'm leaving now, but I hope others will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I see that it is impossible to obtain the exact solution for this question, since it needs a numerical solution. I am interested because I see it may be a real world calculation, based on the numbers given.

I will propose two methods.

(1) Since there are 13 equations and 9 $x_i$, we can propose a $f(x)$ with 4 parameters. For example, let: $$f(x) = ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$$ This system of equations would be very complex, and need a numerical way to find the solution.

(2) Assume that: $$f(x) = ax+b$$ and then use least square method to find the best fit of the line.